# Como montar uma url no Django?

Tags: python, url, django, python-2.7

To aprendendo Django, mas uma coisa que até agora não entendi muito bem é, como montar uma url, sei que ela usa expressão regular, mas alguém aí tem como me explicar, ou me indicar um material que seja bom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente,

é necessário definir uma url, uma 'view' e um nome para url.

```
# urls.py

from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^expressao_regular/$', 'app.views.minha_view', name="nome_da_url"),
    #  mais urls ...
)
```

Quando a página que o usuário está acessando corresponder a uma das urls, o Django faz uma chamada a 'view' correspondente.

Para facilitar você pode chamar a url nos templates da seguinte forma.

Ex:

```
<a href="{% url 'nome_da_url' %}">link</a>
```

Existem outros tópicos interessantes como urls aninhadas e padrões de expressões regulares que vão facilitar sua vida. Para maiores informações consulte a documentação do Django na parte de urls.

[Documentação do Django - Urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/)

Aconselho fortemente a fazer o tutorial que está na documentação.