# Chamando trecho em HTML no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, python, django

estou utilizando Django FrameWork para uma aplicação que pesquisa videos no youtube. Porém tem um trecho de JS, que chama um html onde "embenda" o video pesquisado. E eu não to sabendo como criar essa rota no Django.

**JS que busca o video**

```
function tplawesome(e,t){res=e;for(var n=0;n<t.length;n++){res=res.replace(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/g,function(e,r){return t[n][r]})}return res}

$(function() {
    $("form").on("submit", function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       // prepare the request
       var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
            part: "snippet",
            type: "video",
            q: encodeURIComponent($("#search").val()).replace(/%20/g, "+"),
            maxResults: 3,
            order: "viewCount",
            publishedAfter: "2015-01-01T00:00:00Z"
       });
       // execute the request
       request.execute(function(response) {
          var results = response.result;
          $("#results").html("");
          $.each(results.items, function(index, item) {
            $.get("busca/item.html", function(data) {
                $("#results").append(tplawesome(data, [{"title":item.snippet.title, "videoid":item.id.videoId}]));
            });
          });
          resetVideoHeight();
       });
    });

    $(window).on("resize", resetVideoHeight);
});
```

**HTML que o JS CHAMA**

```
<div class="item">
    <h2>{{title}}</h2>
    <iframe class="video w100" width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/{{videoid}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

**Arquivo views.py onde crio a rota para o arquivo HTML ser renderizado**

```
def busca(request):
    return render(request, 'busca/item.html')
```

**Quando efetuo a pesquisa, ta dando 404 no busca/item.html**

Comment: busca é uma pasta, django nao permite essa chamada... da 404 @NoobSaibot

Comment: Sim. urls.py da app busca:     path('busca/', views.busca, name='busca')

Comment: Eu quero passar o caminho onde ta o HTML, que vai ser renderizado para embedar o video. Nao necessariamente vai abrir uma nova pagina

Comment: Ainda creio que a url no jQuery deva ser: **busca/** foi como você definiu no arquivo urls

Comment: Era isso mesmo @NoobSaibot, Obrigado Pela ajuda

Comment: Lembre-se: `path(rota, view, ...)` como esta na [documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.1/ref/urls/), nessa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48592) também explica.